# Typescript not assignable error after explicit type check

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given the following function that returns a JSX component:

```
const getListContent = () => {
    switch (true) {
        case loading:
            return <ListLoadingIndicator/>;
        case error !== undefined:
            return <ListError error={error}/>;
        default:
            return <ListContent/>
    }
};
```

The Typescript compiler complains that `error` is not assignable to the `ListError` component because the `ListError` interface expects `error` to be of type `Error` but this component's interface allows for a type of `Error | undefined`.

Adding a bang `<ListError error={error!}/>` fixes the issue but I want to understand why the compiler thinks that `error` may be undefined after I explicitly check that it's not.

Comment: Where does `error` gets initialized? If the initial type of this variable is not matching `Error | undefined`, this is where the error comes from.

Comment: @KevinPastor - thanks! The error in this interface can be either an `Error` or `undefined`. The issue comes from TypeScript's handling of the switch statement as pointed out below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, control flow analysis for `switch` statements in TypeScript will narrow the type of the switched value, not the type of other values.  So, `switch (true) {}` will only possibly narrow `true` to something else, which is not useful to you.  And it doesn't look like the TypeScript folks [have any interest in changing this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8934), at least as of 2016.

My suggestion is to do your `if` or `switch` or `?` tests directly on values you'd like to narrow.  If you want `error` to narrow from `Error | undefined` to just `Error`, you should be checking `error` directly.  For example, the following should work:

```
const getListContent = () => {
  if (loading) return <ListLoadingIndicator />;
  if (error !== undefined) return <ListError error={error} />;
  return <ListContent />
};
```

which suggests the following terser syntax:

```
const getListContent = () =>
  loading ? <ListLoadingIndicator /> :
    error ? <ListError error={error} /> :
      <ListContent />;
```

which should also work.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is some discussion of it here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2214 where `electricessence` basically states that switch statements that are not constants, while allowed, are non-normative cases and so not all features may work as expected.  Basically this is not something that TypeScript currently handles.  You could open a feature request for it.  I couldn't find an open one in my brief search.